# How to retain query parameters alongside anchor links after section change event in fullpage.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

Whenever I append a query string in the url of a page containing FullPageJS, this querystring is removed on section change event. I want it to be retained even after section is changed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to open an issue for it in [the github issues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues).

As far as I can see the only solutions for it at the moment are:

- Remove your `anchors` option from your initialisation to stop using anchors in fullpage.js
- Use the query string before any anchor is added to the URL. Try this url for example: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/?demo=aaa

Comment: Hey Alvaro,I have added a new issue [#2900](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2900) on the github forum for this. Thanks,